# Not Able To use simple service in the angular 2 component, getting compilation errors visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, angular, service, compiler-errors

[image]

```js
<!--Simple Angular2 Service-->

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class HomeService {
    constructor() {

    }

    getSomething() {
        return 'hiii';
    }
}

  <!--Consuming Service in Component-->

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomeService } from './components/home/home.service';

@Component({
   selector:'home',
   templateUrl:'app/components/home/home.html'
})
export class HomeComponent { 
  
}

 <!--I am Getting below compilation Errors-->

Error TS2307 Cannot find module 'app/components/home/home.service'.
Error Build:Cannot find module './components/home/home.service'.

Please help stuck here for 3 days
```

Comment: Did you include them in your `@NgModule`?

Comment: yes i have added in the ngmodule providers: [
        HomeService,
        EventHttpService,
        {
            provide: Http,
            useFactory: (xhrBackend: XHRBackend, requestOptions: RequestOptions) => new EventHttpService(xhrBackend, requestOptions),
            deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
        }
    ]

Comment: there are no compilation errors in the app module but there are errors in the component, not sure why my component is not detecting the service :(

Comment: You are injecting it inside your components constructor right?

Comment: no should i inject in the components constructor??

Comment: How else you're going to use it?

Comment: does not make any difference  constructor(homeService: HomeService) {

    }

Comment: i am getting compilation errors in visual studio

Comment: it should be `private homeService: HomeService` in the constructor

Comment: where exactly are you getting compilation errors? In the import to your component, or where?

Comment: In the import of my component

Comment: i am not getting any error in the import of app module, there are compilation errors only in the import of the component

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCdIu.png please take a look at the screen shot

Comment: Have you tried building your project with npm to rule out any issues with Visual Studio?

Comment: Looked at your pictur, seems you have wrong path

Comment: the path is right buddy @AJT_82

Comment: @flesk can you please tell me how to build using npm

Comment: @YogendharReddy Typically you have one or multiple scripts configured in your package.json, but as a minimum you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntypescript to transpile your TypeScript code to Javascript, and then you run it with a web server like, eg. https://www.npmjs.com/package/lite-server

Comment: @YogendharReddy And you're 100% sure the service is in the same directory as home.html and is named home.service.ts?

Comment: @flesk finally the issue got resolved , the path which i used was wrong :D